# Javascript Replace value from var

Tags: javascript, replace

Can anyone help me with this script?
I have to replace the value of a variable in a string (string variables are dynamic)

Here's an example:

```
var string = "#sport,#fotogallery,#sport,"; 
var element = "#sport"; 
string.replace(element+",","");
alert(string);
```

Comment: and what's the desired result? (even though you named your variable `array` what you have written above is not of an array type)

Comment: Are we to assume your array is actually an array and not a string? `var array = ['#sport','#fotogallery','#sport']; `

Comment: Is it an array (`["#sport", "#fotogallery"]`) or a string (`"#sport,#fotogallery`)?

Comment: Here's some great documentation on Javascript Array's https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: `replace` returns a **new** string.

Comment: sorry, it's a string not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `replace` function **returns** a string, it does not mutate the variable. So, proper usage is as follows:

```
source = source.replace('old', 'new');
```

You should take care to ensure that your input is in the exact format, because if there is no trailing comma after the last value, and you want to replace the last value, then simply using `replace` would fail.

Comment: Make the replace global too (via `g` RegEx flag); if you just use a raw `.replace()` it'll only replace the _first_ instance of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all instances of `element` followed by an optional comma:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(element + ",?", "g"), "")
```

Your string appears to be delimited, so this is also an option:

```
var str = "#sport,#fotogallery,#sport,"; 
var element = "#sport"; 
var newStr = str.split(",").filter(function(el) {
    return el !== element;
}).join(",");
```

Or, if you can't use `filter`, this will work, too:

```
var parts = str.split(",");
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i] !== element)
        res.push(parts[i]);
}
var newStr = res.join(",");
```